# Currently trying to use my MobileNet in a web application, nothing seems to work

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow.js, conv-neural-network

EDIT:
The issue was the h5 file I saved before converting to tfjs. If you try something similar use the method save instead of save_weights when saving your keras model.

My project is supposed to identify me or my friends in any given image.
I have trained a Mobile CNN made with keras and transformed it with tensorflowjs [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vPun.png)

I have followed a few tutorials and I still can't understand why my model won't load. This is part of my script:

```js
let model;

async function loadMyModel() {
  model = undefined;

  model = await tf.loadLayersModel("https://consumingtoast.github.io/SelfieTime/model/model.json");
  $('.progress-bar').hide();
  alert("model loaded..");

}

try {
  loadMyModel();
} catch {
  alert("Something went wrong");
}
```

Comment: Do you have an error ?

Comment: No alerts popped up, then I changed the catch to print the error in the console like this: console.log("Error", e.stack); and again nothing showed up.

Comment: What are you expecting the code to do ? There is no error which means that the model has been successfully loaded